# What can be done to reduce the CPU utilization, or let the CPUs work balance, so as to improve the performance of graphics program?

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, cpu-usage, vxworks

My Graphics program with OpenGL ES 2.0  runs in VxWorks SMP (dual core), through the spy command, it is found that one CPU utilization rate is close to 100%, and the other CPU is almost in idle state. Meanwhile, the drawing performance of the program (measured by frames per second ) drops more than that of single core in VxWorks UP. What can be done to reduce the CPU utilization, or let the CPUs work balance, so as to improve the  performance of graphics program?
(the OS version is VxWorks 6.9,  using the ARMARCH7gnu compiler with the windriver workbench 3.3, and the program runs on the dual core development board of armv8 architecture.)

Comment: It's very hard to multithread OpenGLES in any meaningful way. If you're looking to offload work onto the other CPU, then I'd recommend you look at moving bits of application logic instead. The biggest thing to reduce the CPU cost of OpenGLES is usually to reduce the number of draw calls through culling and batching. I'm not familiar with VxWorks though, this is just general advice from using OpenGLES on other platforms.

Answer (score 0):

You might check with taskCpuAffinitySet() to leverage manually the load balancing on your system.
If you could use the system viewer you might be able to identify the behavior and see what is explaining the FPS drop.